# Number of mappers in job

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

my problem is that.

How many mapper will be created in mapreduce job, to process two very small files, with content:

file 1:
1 John
2 Mary

file 2:
3. Peter
4. Brad

Many it will be two mappers? or we have to know size of hdfs block?
we can not set up such a small block size.
Minimum block is 64 MB?

Comment: Answer is 2..hadoop will never concatenate 2 files for you even if they are way smaller/bigger than the block sizes...default is 64 for hdfs not minimum

Comment: @Cugar if you want to process two file in single map it is possible to give multiple file path